# wpf, Button to check a checkbox, while the checkbox IsChecked is bound to something else

Tags: c#, wpf, button, checkbox, command

I have a button lives in View1. View1 has ViewModel1. I have a CheckBox that lives in View2. View2 has ViewModel2. Now if I wanted to use a button command to check the Checkbox (Note that the CheckBox IsChecked is already bound to something else). So just for practicing and try to make it work, I made a class called Commands like shown below. then I made another class called CommandsViewModel as shown below, that will be used by the button to show a MessageBox. Now how to make it check the CheckedBox to instead of showing the MessageBox.

Here is the Commands Class

```
public class Commands : ICommand
{
    Action<object> executeMethod;
    Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod;

    public Commands(Action<object> executeMethod, Func<object, bool> canExecuteMethod)
    {
        this.executeMethod = executeMethod;
        this.canExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        executeMethod(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Here is the CommadsViewModel Class

```
public class CommandsViewModel
{
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }
    public CommandsViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new Commands(ExecuteMethod, canExecuteMethod);
    }

    private bool canExecuteMethod(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void ExecuteMethod(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Command executed!");
    }
}
```

Here is the button

```
<Button Content="Select All"
       Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source={StaticResource cmdvm}}"
       MinWidth="150" Margin="0,5,20,20">
```

Here is the Checkbox

```
<CheckBox
        Name="myCB"
        Content="{Binding ItemName}" 
        IsChecked="{Binding ItemIsChecked}"/>
```

Comment: Could you please tell which view invokes the other? View1 invokes View2 or vice versa? You cannot directly set the IsChecked of the other view without accessing it's view model or view, that's why you will have to access the IsCheked property through a view model or raise a delegate on the button click to which the other view model will register.

Comment: I'm actually not sure that any of the Views invokes the other.

Comment: How will you be able to check a checkbox on a view which has not been invoked? So let's if you invoke View2 from View1 then you will have the instance of it's view model and that's how you can set the IsChecked property in the view model. If in case the checkbox is on the parent view and not the child view (the one invoked is child) then you will have to use a delegate and register the same in the child and in it's event handler you can set the property of the checkbox.

Comment: ok, so if I understood the Invoke and was able to implement it in either way you explained, I still cannot use the IsChecked because as you can see IsChecked="{Binding ItemIsChecked}"/> is  already bound to something else.

Comment: By IsChecked what I meant was the ItemIsChecked property inside the view model. Make sure the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is implemented and notify the same in it's setter. Change the binding to to as follows: IsChecked="{Binding ItemIsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: Thank you Sir, will try that. Also appreciate if others give solution or comments.

Comment: You simply need to set the `ItemIsChecked` property to `true`. That of course means your command implementation needs access to the `ViewModel2` where that property (presumably) is implemented. Your question does not provide enough context to write an actual answer, but that is the general approach you need to take. If you want a real answer, fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve] clearly illustrating the scenario.

Comment: thank you Sir, you just gave me a great idea, I will try it if it didn't work I will fix the question.